# Pygame Screen Size to Large

Tags: python, window, pygame, size, screen

I have a problem with my pygame display. I am making it the same size as my screens dimension, so when I fullscreen it there will be no black borders around the edges. I am using current_w and current_h before generating a pygame display to do this. But when I run the game the display is to big and I can't see it all in fullscreen. It is not a problem with the fullscreen though, if I turn fullscreen off the window is too large and can't fit onto my screen. I have printed out the results of current_w and current_h, getting 1920 and 1080, which are the right numbers, my computer screen resolution being those numbers. The problem doesn't seem to be with the fullscreen or the resolution, so I have no idea what is wrong.

So to sum my problem up:

- I want a pygame display with the same size as my screen resolution
- The display is to large, unable to fit onto my screen
- Despite this, the display's dimensions match up with those of my screen resolution

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks

The code I am using to get my screen size and create the display are:

```
infoObject = pygame.display.Info()
display = pygame.display.set_mode((infoObject.current_w, infoObject.current_h))
```

I have tried fullscreen, as I mentioned previously, like this:

```
display = pygame.display.set_mode((infoObject.current_w,inforObject.current_h),pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

Comment: How are you setting the sreensize, can you should us the code doing this settings.

Comment: Have you tried using pygame.FULLSCREEN inside pygame.display.set_mode()?

Comment: Is it only missing a little or a lot?